# How do I create a RAID 1 on HP Proliant DL360 with P410i controller?

Tags: raid

It seems there is only an option for:

Raid 1+0
Raid 0

I got two Disk, and wish to do a mirror. What are the options for me? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can't by definition have a RAID 1+0 disk array with only two disks. Create an array as RAID 1+0 with two disks you will have a RAID 1 array.

Comment: Ravi isn't trying to do RAID 10, he just doesn't see the option to create a RAID 1. You should probably delete your "answer".

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem with my "answer" is. HP don't differentiate between RAID1+0 and RAID1 in the array tool. I've dug out a copy the HP Array Configuration Utility User Guide (http://docs.hp.com/en/9320/acu.pdf) which confirms it on page 62

Comment: +1 This is the correct answer - not sure other than HP does it but it's basically standard to use RAID1+0 as the "generically named" formula and applied to two disks it will actually just be a RAID1 array. May sound weird but that's how it's been for a long time now and it actually makes a little sense, if you want a generic name for mirroring across a random number of discs this is basically it, quirky as it may be ^^

Answer (score 1):

According to the manual, http://bizsupport1.austin.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c00729544/c00729544.pdf , if you're in the BIOS ROM utility ("ORCA"), they term a RAID-1 (mirror) as a "RAID 1+0".  Select the controller, press F8, select the drives and RAID level, confirm, and exit the utility.

Answer (score 1):

If firmware version HP Smart Array P420i Controller is older then
3.04, only RAID 1+0 is available and should be used

Answer (score 0):

The p410i supports for sure raid 1.
Are you trying with the bios utility or smart start?

Comment: Doing it with bios utility. Smart start only shows Raid 0/Array and I see no options for Raid 1 there either.

Comment: Has the controller a cache? Is the Zero Memory Raid (ZMR) enabled?
Did you try to upgrade all the bioses?

Comment: I am seeing 0% Read/0%Write in Cache ratio. Does that mean it doesn't have a cache? Can't find option for ZMR.

Comment: I bought this server in November 2009, and it's a G6. Will it be necessary to make a Bios upgrade?

Comment: On my servers I try to keep the bios up to date. All the bioses for your server can be downloaded with this cd  http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareIndex.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodNameId=3884320&prodTypeId=15351&prodSeriesId=3884319&swLang=13&taskId=135&swEnvOID=1005#2913  
It find automatically every update your machine needs.

Comment: This raid controller, as far as i know, has limitations only if you want to create more then 2 logical volume. But, even without cache and battery, you should able to create raid 0/1/1+0